# How to set a textview's text to a string created by receiving text from an app action extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am playing around with action extensions and looked at Apple's documents and found this code.

```
NSExtensionContext *myExtensionContext = self.extensionContext;
NSArray *inputItems = myExtensionContext.inputItems;
```

Then I change the array to a string.

```
NSString * resultString = [inputItems  componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Then, I set the text view to the resultString string.

```
textView.text = resultString;
```

What I have been getting is

```
<NSExtensionItem: 0x174002840> - userInfo: {NSExtensionItemAttachmentsKey = ("<NSItemProvider: 0x17424c900> {types = (\n    \"public.plain-text\"\n)}");}
```

that appears in my text view.

Code snippet from `viewDidLoad:`

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSExtensionContext *myExtensionContext = self.extensionContext;
NSArray *inputItems = myExtensionContext.inputItems;
NSString * resultString = [inputItems  componentsJoinedByString:@""];
textView.text = resultString;
```

Comment: What is being displayed in UITextView is absolutely correct! Could specify what is the problem you are facing? and what you want to show in the TextView?

Answer (score 1):

Actually following code will return array of `NSExtensionItem` not a `NSString` type so you can not parse directly using
`NSString * resultString = [inputItems  componentsJoinedByString:@""];`

To Parse `NSArray` of `NSExtensionItems`, You need to do following things. Here I assume that 'NSDictionary' as input type.

```
for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
    for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
        if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:@"typeIdentifier"]) {
            // This is an image. We'll load it, then place it in our image view.

            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"typeIdentifier" options:nil completionHandler:^(id<NSSecureCoding> item, NSError *error) {

                NSDictionary* tempDict = (NSDictionary*)item;
                NSLog(@"Dectionary : %@",item);

            }];

        }
    }
}
```

For More details [Action Extension tutorial](https://jptext.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/action-extension-tutorial/) may help you.